# Wanna make the color more thinner on Canvas, depending on the depth

Tags: javascript, canvas, formula, rgb

Now I'm making a web application about mind map, by using canvas.

The problem is that I wanna make the mindmap's line to be more thinner or weaker

depending on the node's depth.

What i did is to set some colors on the array 'depColor'.

But this is temporary solution,

and i wanna make a formula for the RGB color.

Is there any way to make the color more weaker

by calculating the codes of rgb color?

```
var depColor = ["#0061ff", "#2678ff", "#4e90fc", "#70a6ff", "#89b5ff", "#a8c8ff", "#bcd5ff"];

ctx.strokeStyle = depColor[savedArray[i].depth % 7];
```

Comment: Did you try to use colors as rgb values with opacity? Like 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)'.

Comment: I'm not very sure what a _thinner color_ is, but you can - as @İbrahimÖzcan advises you - use `rgba` or `hsla` colors. Also you can use  `hsl` colors and change the saturation or lightness. This is a nice article where you can find lots of formulas to [convert color spaces in JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/converting-color-spaces-in-javascript/).

Comment: Thx for the comment! I'll try first!!